# Need a better/optimised way to list files according to the pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-databricks

I am trying to list files from Azure data lake storage using a pattern using os.walk. It is too slow and not accepted by the business. Is there any faster way to do this?

**code snippet below:**

```
# pattern holds something like '201707' (YYYYMM) as files are dated.
pattern="*{0}*.*".format(batch_no)
print(pattern)
files_list=[]
  #os Walk to get file paths
for root in root_list:
  for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
      if fnmatch(name.upper(), pattern.upper()):
        files_list.append(str(batch_no)+path.replace("dbfs/","")+"/"+name)
```

Comment: You could try to use the python module: multithreading to start an os.walk() each root files

Comment: You can profile your code, identify the hot spots and work on it.

Comment: @ÉmerickPoulin I thought the same. Thanks. I was actually looking for some kind of difference between os.walk or dbutils.fs.ls or glob. So that I can use the faster one.

Comment: Do the files all exist in one directory or do you need to search sub-directories?

Comment: @BrutusForcus I need to go scan sub directories for files. we have categorization for files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that you could use to get all the files that match your pattern. Invoke with recursive=True if you need to examine sub-directories:

```
import glob
import os

def getBatchFiles(root, batch, recursive=False):
    pattern = f'*{batch}*.*'
    gp = os.path.join(root, '**', pattern) if recursive else os.path.join(root, pattern)
    return glob.glob(gp, recursive=recursive)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question how to make it faster, you need to first answer the question "why it is slow?".

To answer that question, you will need to *profile* your code.
You could use `cProfile` from the standard library, or an external one like [line_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/).

Running your code through the profiler will show you which parts take the most time. Once you've identified those you can think of alternatives.

I would hazard a guess that retrieving the names from the azure cloud storage is what takes the most time. Maybe there is a different (faster) API you can use for that?